# How can I listen an element's attribute change in an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

here's a [<kbd>plunker</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/zmiMQjq2D5C1bBraPzjU?p=preview), it pretty well exposes what I'm trying to do.

I have a directive with ! **isolated scope** ! with an attribute that is intended to be changed

```
<div ng-init="environment='natural'">
  <input ng-model=environment>
  <chameleon env="{{ environment }}"></chameleon>
</div>
```

I want my directive to response to global scope's changes :

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('chameleon', function () { return {

  template: 'I am {{ color }}',
  scope: {} // isolated

  ,link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$watch('env', function () {
       scope.color = getColor();
    });

    function getColor () {
       switch (attrs.env) {
          case 'excited': return 'red';
          ...
          case 'natural':
          default: return 'green';
       }
    }

        /* here I need something similar to this not-working code :
         *   element.on('attributeChange', function () {
         *      scope.env = attrs.env
         *   });
         */
  }

}});
```

I know I can use the isolated scope to bind values of the surrounding scope, like

```
scope: {
  env: '='
}
```

but I really need to have an independent component as the value of the attribute `env` is not only going to be changed from the model.

feel free to fork my plunker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `attrs.$observe` that will work as the same as `$watch`. It works on `{{}}` value & change in value will call the `$observe` function.

**Code**

```
attrs.$observe('env', function() {
     scope.color = getColor();
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aJojItnwWj5bwUKXSUSN?p=preview)

Comment: oh my ! just when I thought my issue was about to be of a pain to resolve. thanks ! but I think it should be written this way `attrs.$observe('env', ...`

Comment: yeah! my Chameleon is alive !

Comment: @Pankar Parkar , how to listen to a change in ng-disabled="" ? in the directive e.g <mydirective ng-disabled="expression">. So mydirective needs to know and execute code if there is a change in ng-disabled

Comment: `$scope.$watch(function() { return expression ;}, function(newValue, oldValue) { // your code here.
});`